# How to rotate Circuitikz circuit as a whole?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I've drawn a circuit path using CircuiTikZ library. Now I want to rotate the circuit as a whole. The nodes of circuit are transform correctly. However the circuit elements do not get rotated at all.

By using a scope environment with the rotate parameter

```
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
    \draw (0,2) to[L] (4,2)
        to[short] (4,-2)
        to[C] (0,-2)
        to[short] (0,2);
\end{scope}
```

I end up with this:

[image: Failed rotation of CircuiTikZ path.]

If it matters, I'm drawing this inside a *tikzpicture* environment.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The circuit elements are probably defined as nodes, and node shapes are by default not influenced by `rotate`. To enable rotating for those as well, add `transform shape` to the `scope` settings:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[rotate=30,transform shape]
    \draw (0,2) to[L] (4,2)
        to[short] (4,-2)
        to[C] (0,-2)
        to[short] (0,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Despite avoiding 'thanks' comments: Thank you, for the fast and correct answer.