# circuitikz rotate transformer

Tags: circuitikz

Is it possible to rotate transformer without using scope?
Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
            (0,0) node [transformer](t1){}
            (0,-3.5) node [transformer, rotate = 30](t2){}
        ;
        \begin{scope}[shift = {(3.5,-1.75)}, rotate=30, transform shape]
            \draw
                (0,0) node [transformer](t3){}
            ;
        \end{scope}
        \draw
            (t1.B1) to [R]
            ++(right:2)
            (t2.B1) to [R]
            ++(right:2)
            (t3.B1) to [R]
            ++(right:2)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image: outputOfCode]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry. I copied the code with "scope" from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166620/how-to-rotate-circuitikz-circuit-as-a-whole). Then I realized the word "transform shape". Then I tried it as direct argument and it worked.
Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw
            (0,0) node [transformer](t1){}
            (0,-3.5) node [transformer, rotate = 30](t2){}
            (3.5,-1.75) node [transformer, rotate = 30, transform shape](t3){}
        ;
        \draw
            (t1.B1) to [R]
            ++(right:2)
            (t2.B1) to [R]
            ++(right:2)
            (t3.B1) to [R]
            ++(right:2)
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image: outputOfCode]